# Asp.net Minimal API find by username(string)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I want to create endpoint which return the data by username(string).

Finding by id is working. It list the data with the given id.

```
app.MapGet("/store/{id}", async (StoreDb db, int id) => await db.Stores.FindAsync(id))
   .RequireAuthorization();
```

But using name(string) is not working.

```
app.MapGet("/store/{name}", async (StoreDb db, string name) => await db.Stores.FindAsync(name))
   .RequireAuthorization();
```

Schema :

```
Store {
    id integer($int32)
    name string
}
```

Json :

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the method FindAsync tries to find your record using the id, you're only passing a different data in his parameter, what you should do is something like this

```
app.MapGet("/store/{name}", async (StoreDb db, string name) => await db.Stores.Where(s => s.name == name).FirstOrDefault()).RequireAuthorization();
```

But retrieving by name can generate some problems when there's redundant names so you should change `FirstOrDefault()` to `ToListAsync()` which is better for this case

```
app.MapGet("/store/{name}", async (StoreDb db, string name) => await db.Stores.Where(s => s.name == name).ToListAsync()).RequireAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thanks kyble . Its working but since it's async operation, i have to add ToListAsync().